# Pycharm и неправильная кодировка UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, pycharm, кодировка

Когда я пытаюсь вывести какой-либо русский текст в консоли, я получаю ����.
File Encoding и IDE Encoding установлены на UTF-8, поэтому не понимаю в чем проблема. Она появилась только после обновления на 5 версию PyCharm, еще на 4.5.4 такой проблемы не возникало.

[image: Пишу русский текст]

Answer (score 0):

1) В файлике **PYCHARM_HOME/bin/pycharm.exe.vmoptions** или **PYCHARM_HOME/bin/pycharm.vmoptions** пропишите:

```
-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
```

2) В самом начале файлика **mail.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

3) Ну и проверить с какой кодировкой вообще файл сохранён. Нужно, чтоб в Utf-8, а не ASCII был. Плюс, если там есть BOM символ вначале файла, удалить его.

Comment: не сработало. В IDLE(родном редакторе) все работает, в CLion и IDEA тоже все работает...